# How to add fillet between 2 curves in eyeshot

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I found the method for Chamfer and fillet but could not really understand the implementation of it.
Basically I am not able to evoke Fillet property.

http://documentation.devdept.com/100/WPF/topic4434.html

If anybody can guide.

Code:

```
ICurve line1 = new Line(0, 0, 0, 57.06, 0, 0);

ICurve line2 = new Line(0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0);
```

So how do I fillet between these 2 lines. I cant locate Fillet method to pass these ICurves.

Adding the image, for better understanding of problem. As you can see I am not able to invoke Curve class and subsequently fillet property. I am using Eyeshot version 12

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Coj.png)

Image of all the dll added, but still same error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/617NH.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty straight forward. Can you show your code that is not working ? your 2 ICurve need to be on the same plane and they need to touch on one point.

Comment: Hi @Franck added code.

Comment: Your `ICurve` are 2 simple `Line` at 90°. They both touch on the start. All you have to pay attention is to put a realistic radius where it at least leaves a little bit on both lines. But the method should work with these lines. I have personally never used it but it's like any CAD fillet. first 2 params are your lines, order matter for the next parameters, Flip1 i assume will flip the first curve param and so one on the other parameters. Flip is because fillet can be started from 2 points (start or end) so this allow you to switch. Trim is if you want to cut what the fillet replaces.

Comment: Thanks franck for explanation, I added the image of exact problem. There's no Curve class only.

Comment: `Curve` class do exist. The class is accessible from the `devDept.Eyeshot.Control.Win.XXXXXX.DLL`. If you drag an drop a viewport layout in a `Form` it will automatically include that dll in your reference, then you should be able to access it like so :  `devDept.Eyeshot.Entities.Curve.Fillet()`

Comment: I added image showing my references. Tried adding all available dlls, still no luck.

Comment: Ahhhh i see. You don't have the ultimate version. You need Nurbs to have access to those features.

Comment: So getting ultimate version will solve the issue ?

Comment: you need to contact DevDept directly to make sure but as far as i remember and what the website state Nurbs and other very advanced 3D stuff are part of the Ultimate version

Comment: ohkk Thanks. Will check.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go bud.  Hopefully this is a decent start.  I set flip 1 to be true, so that line1's end point is at the start of line 2.  (I didn't actually plot this, but I think that's what they're asking for)
I also made the assumption you want to trim lines 1 and 2.
Eyeshots documentation on their website is pretty decent.  Reading those can definitely help you understand the constructors a little better.
The output of the fillet command is an arc, which makes sense.  You will most likely need to add myFillet seperately from lines 1 and 2 to the viewport, as they are all separate entities.

```
      ICurve line1 = new Line(0, 0, 0, 57.06, 0, 0);
      ICurve line2 = new Line(0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0);

      double radius = 10.0;
      bool flip1 = true;
      bool flip2 = false;
      bool trim1 = true;
      bool trim2 = true;

      Arc myFillet;
      Curve.Fillet(line1, line2, radius, flip1, flip2, trim1, trim2, out myFillet);
```

Comment: Are you sure that's supposed to be an html snippet?

Comment: It certainly was not.  Hope that's better.  Good call.